# Ошибка на 41 строке

Tags: asp

Помогите решить проблему.
 Выдает ошибку при отправке.
http://rghost.ru/51172243 - исходник

```
<%@ Page Language=VB Debug=true %>    
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data" %>    
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data.OLEDB" %>    
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Mail" %>    
<script runat=server>    
Sub Page_Load(ByVal Sender as Object, ByVal E as EventArgs)    
    If Not IsPostBack Then    
        Dim DBConn as OleDbConnection
        Dim DBCommand As OleDbDataAdapter    
        Dim DSPageData as New DataSet    
            DBConn = New OleDbConnection("PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" _    
                & "DATA SOURCE=" _    
                & Server.MapPath("" _    
                & "App_Data/C7EmailFile.mdb;"))    
        DBCommand = New OleDbDataAdapter _    
            ("SELECT FileTitle, FileName from Files " _    
            & "Order By FileTitle", DBConn)    
        DBCommand.Fill(DSPageData, _    
            "Files")    
        ddlFiles.DataSource = _    
            DSPageData.Tables("Files").DefaultView    
        ddlFiles.DataBind()    
        lblMessage.Text = "Заполните все поля " _    
            & "и нажмите кнопку OK."    
    End If    
End Sub

Sub SubmitBtn_Click(Sender As Object, E As EventArgs)    
    Dim TheMessage as String    
    Dim TheMailMessage as New MailMessage    
    Dim TheAttachment as New MailAttachment _    
        (Server.MapPath("" _    
        & ddlFiles.SelectedItem.Value))    
    TheMessage = "Спасибо за посещение нашего узла. Выбранный вами файл" _    
        & ": " & ddlFiles.SelectedItem.Text _    
        & " вложен в это письмо."    
    TheMailMessage.From = "webmaster@a.com"    
    TheMailMessage.To = txtEmailAddress.text    
    TheMailMessage.Subject = "Файл"    
    TheMailMessage.Body = TheMessage    
    TheMailMessage.Attachments.Add (TheAttachment)    
    SmtpMail.Send(TheMailMessage)    
    lblMessage.Text = "Выбранный вами файл отправлен по указанному адресу"    
    pnlForm.Visible = False    
End Sub    
</SCRIPT>    
<HTML>    
<HEAD>    
<TITLE>Отправка файла</TITLE>    
</HEAD>    
<BODY BACKGROUND="./bg.jpg" TEXT="black" LINK="darkred" VLINK="darkred" ALINK="red" LEFTMARGIN="20">    
<form id="Form1" runat="server">    
<Font Face="Tahoma">    
<asp:Label     
    id="lblTitle"     
    Font-Size="25pt"    
    Font-Name="Tahoma"    
    Text="Отправка файла"    
    runat="server"    
/>    
<IMG SRC="./line.gif">    
<Font Face="Tahoma">    
<BR><BR>    
<asp:Label     
    id="lblMessage"     
    Font-Size="10pt"    
    Font-Name="Tahoma"    
    Font-Bold="True"    
    runat="server"    
/>    
<asp:Panel     
    id="pnlForm"     
    runat="server"    
> 
<BR><BR>    
<B>Имя файла:</B>   
<BR>   
<asp:dropdownlist    
    id="ddlFiles"     
    runat=server    
    DataTextField="FileTitle"     
    DataValueField="FileName">    
</asp:dropdownlist>    
<BR><BR>    
<B>Адрес электронной почты:</B>    
<BR>    
<asp:TextBox     
    id="txtEmailAddress"     
    Columns="25"    
    MaxLength="50"    
    runat=server     
/>

<asp:RequiredFieldValidator     
    id="rfvEmailAddress"    
    ControlToValidate="txtEmailAddress"    
    Display="Dynamic"    
    Font-Name="Verdana"    
    Font-Size="10pt"    
    runat=server>    
    Необходимо ввести адрес электронной почты!    
</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

<BR><BR>    
<asp:button     
    id="butOK"    
    text="  OK  "    
    Type="Submit"    
    OnClick="SubmitBtn_Click"     
    runat="server"    
/>    
</asp:Panel>    
</Font>    
</Form>    
</BODY>    
</HTML>
```

Comment: может хотя бы скажете, что за ошибка и в какой строке (я имею в виду не номер)? Или предлагаете скачивать ваши исходники, ковыряться в них или считать номера строк?

Comment: Компилирует норм, но при отправке на мыло выдает ошибку и выделяет красным это SmtpMail.Send(TheMailMessage)

Comment: VB в ASP O_O

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю у вас просто нет SMTP сервера или он не отвечает.

Как у вас заданы свойства SmtpMail.Host и SmtpMail.Port... надо их через telnet проверить.